# Swashbuckle doesn't generate nullable: true with [FormData]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.4.0). Whenever I use `[FromForm]` instead of `[FromBody]` to force the content type to multipart/form-data, all of the optional properties of the DTO no longer have `nullable:"true"` in the swagger spec. This causes my client code generator to throw an exception if null is passed in. (I use string in the following example, but it happens with other object that I try to make optional, like IFormFile)

I am trying use multipart/form-data because I am trying to upload a file as part of this DTO, and as far as I understand it, it's better to use multipart/form-data than to use application/json and pass a base64 byte array.

For example, the following DTO and controller:

```
public class TestDTO
{
  public string? SomeProp { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Test([FromForm] TestDTO dto)
  {
    return this.Ok(dto);
  }
}
```

Generates this swagger json:

```
"/api/Test/Test": {
   "post": {
     "tags": [
       "Test"
     ],
     "requestBody": {
       "content": {
         "multipart/form-data": {
           "schema": {
             "type": "object",
             "properties": {
               "SomeProp": {
                 "type": "string"
               }
             }
           },
           "encoding": {
             "SomeProp": {
               "style": "form"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "responses": {
       "200": {
         "description": "Success"
       }
     }
   }
},
```

But if I change the `[FromForm]` to `[FromBody]` it generates this:

```
 "/api/Test/Test": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TourificService.Endpoints.Admin.Controllers.TestDTO"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

```
"TourificService.Endpoints.Admin.Controllers.TestDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "someProp": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
```

Which, as you can see, allows null on SomeProp.

I can manually add `"nullable": true` to the original swagger before sending it to my client code generator and it works, but having to intervene makes the whole point of automatic code generation pointless.